# Inform the instances of Android Activty about data update

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an activity A .It can launch itself many times with data requested from the server or call activity B(like A ->A ->B ->A).If the most recent and currently in foreground, activity A make some edits(delete or update operation)to the data, I want the previous instances of A to reload the data in them.How can I achieve this? I don't want to use startactivityforresult again and again as it will complicate the workflow.Can this be done using broadcast receivers or services? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EventBus to achieve this. Simply register each activity in `onStart()`, and unregister in `onDestroy()`, and when the data comes to whichever activity, simply call `EventBus.getDefault().post(YourDataClass data);` and each activity will receive the data.

Comment: I have already thought of this and to me,it seems that it might become problematic to manage the List<FragmentClass> .Basically I will have to push and pop into the stack the instances and was looking for a more simpler way to achieve it.Is there any other way?Thanks.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using something like EventBus to post the events and then consume them in the Activities if you really want to keep using `Activity` as opposed to `Fragment`.

You can find EventBus here: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: But will it work if the Activtiy is not in foreground and hasn't unregistered from the eventbus after the onstop method? Can the same instance register itself multiple times? Can this be achieved by using broadcast receivers?Thanks.

Comment: You can register multiple times for different classes, and it will still receive the data unless the activity has been destroyed (which is where you should unregister the receiver). You can use Broadcast receivers, I just find EventBus to be a bit easier to use and track.

Comment: Thanks.I will try it out and let you know.Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes using the EventBus is the easiest way to achieve similar tasks.

Comment: @idratherbeintheair It worked. Please edit your answer to include the Eventbus solution as well.Thanks.